# Viewer for huge CSV files which don't fit in memory

Tags: linux, csv

I would like to find a CSV viewer that has the following features:

- Runs on Linux.
- Handles very large files. I mean it should not try to load the entire file in memory at any time (unlike LibreOffice Calc).
- Allows to read anywhere in the file with a scrollbar or something equivalent.
- Displays a tabular view of the data (columns are vertically aligned) and allow the user to resize the columns (unlike regular text editor).
- Ideally makes a sensible guess about the delimiter and the quotechar.
- Ideally guesses the encoding.

Comment: Do you want a pager like `less` or do you have specific line ranges you want to pull out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [reCsvEditor](http://recsveditor.sourceforge.net/csv02.htm), a CSV file viewer/editor which supports a wide variety of field delimiters, very large files and Unicode Files. Files are displayed in a table format.

It seems to match all your requirements, it's written in Java, and it has a [SourceForge project portal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/recsveditor/) too (where the program can be downloaded from).

Here is a list of features, taken from its website:

> - Supports for very large Files
> - Supports just about any character being used as a field separator
> - Columns can be added, moved and copied
> - Field Separator / Quotes can be changed
> - Fields can be both hidden and Fixed in position
> - Multiple File Views are Supported including
>
>   - Record View - Display a single record with fields going down the page.
>   - Filtered View - Select Records / Fields to be displayed.
>   - Sorted Tree View - Gives a Sort / Summary of the file with individual records as leaf's in the tree
>   - Column View - Rows / Columns swapped.
> - Files can be exports as Fixed Width Text or Xml or Html or via Velocity Template (needs separate velocity Download).

A few screenshots to give you an idea of how it looks:

[image: CSV file preview]

[image: CSV record edit view]

[image: CSV big file options]

Comment: The sourceforge page states that it is a "Editor for simple (only one record) Csv Files".  Do you know what the "only one record" means?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I've read that as well, no idea what it means... I've used the program and you can definitely edit more than one record of a CSV file.

Comment: LOL.  Yes, it seems like a very odd thing to be able to only edit one record!  Perhaps it is a translation error.  Glad to hear it does not have that limitation.  ;)

Comment: It seems to be the perfect tool. Unfortunately the window doesn't show properly on ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: This is the perfect tool ! Besides, it is actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is loading your CSV file into a analytics-oriented DBMS, like [MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/), then using its simple command-line client or any ODBC/JDBC/MAPI-based tools - to view only those parts of the data you're interested in. With SQL you can easily apply all sorts of complex, or simple, filters - on the columns and the rows.